# How to get elements added in html editor

Tags: html, vb.net, string, ckeditor

I have an html editor (**ckeditor**) in my vb.net application. after the user adds controls(buttons, input, text...) in the editor, he clicks on a button. after clicking that button i want to take all the elements added from that html editor... is there any way i can do it?  I can get the text as string, but is there a way i can "transform" that string into html and get all the tags/controls added? ]

I'm new at this so please, excuse my errors. Thank you!

this is the function fired after button click
'ckeditor ID = "TBHTMLText"

```
    Protected Sub btnGetElements_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetElements.Click
            dim textAddedByUser as string
            textAddedByUser = TBHTMLText.Text
    End Sub
```

this textAddedByUser is everything the user adds in the editor so I was thinking if i develop an algorithm that can help me take every single tag and get the ID of each control added... but I think there is an easier way to do it. If so help me please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about vb.net but with JavaScript you might have a listener for CKEditor's "change" event. Or, if you wanted to get the content from an editor instance upon the triggering of some arbitrary event, you could use CKEditor's getData() method. This would give you the raw HTML.

Examples:

When an arbitrary event is fired:

```
var editor = $(e.currentTarget).ckeditorGet();
var data = editor.getData();
var el = editor.element.$;
```

Setting up a "change" listener for CKEditor instances:

```
$.each(CKEDITOR.instances, function(i, editor) { 
    editor.on("change", function(e) {
        var data = e.sender.getData();
        var el = editor.element.$;
        ...
    });
});
```